# How to generate locally the documentation for an imported pod

Tags: fantom

The script `buildwebdocs.fan` generates the documentation for the distribution's pods, but not for the pods I did myself or imported. How can I generate the documentation locally for this pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `compilerDoc` yourself:

```
$ fan compilerDoc -?

Usage:
  compilerDoc [options] <pods>*
Arguments:
  pods    Name of pods to compile (does not update index)
Options:
  -help, -?         Print usage help
  -all              Generate docs for every installed pods
  -allCore          Generation docs for Fantom core pods
  -clean            Delete outDir
  -outDir <File>    Output dir for doc files
```

So for you local pod:

```
$ fan compilerDoc myPod
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky question, and one I don't have an immediate answer (or script) for. However, assuming you only wish to *view* the documentation and don't require a directory of HTML files, then I can offer an alternative...

Install and use the [Explorer](http://eggbox.fantomfactory.org/pods/afExplorer/) application. It's a desktop file explorer application that, amongst other things, includes a [Fandoc Viewer](http://eggbox.fantomfactory.org/pods/afExplorer/doc/#fandocViewer) that lets you view documentation from pods in the current Fantom installation.

Example, to view the documentation for the `afReflux` pod, type `afReflux` (case-insensitive) in the address bar:

[image]

You can also press <kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up an index page of all installed Fantom pods.